# How To Run Tests classes With Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, testng

I Have TestNg Class look like the following code:
And I have On Jenkins two jobs: job1 and job2 job1 to execute TestsFluxPro   and job2 to execute TestsVente tests 
my question is how to configure Jenkins to tell in each job run the chosen class test for example in job 1 I want to execute com. AZ. testsFlux. TestsVente!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" 
 />
    <listener class-name="com.az.utilities.CustomListeners" />
</listeners>
<test name="Managetestss" group-by-instances="true">
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"></parameter>
    <classes>
    <class name="com.az.testsFlux.TestsFluxPro" />
    <class name="com.az.testsFlux.TestsVente" />

    </classes>
</test>
 </suite>
```

Comment: You can create two testng xml's for different jobs, add the classes that it is supposed to run and specify the respective testng.xml for each job.

Answer (score 0):

Reconsider using [testng.xml](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml), you will not be able to parameterize it from Jenkins.

There is a possibility to run your [TestNG](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/TestNG) test [in command-line mode](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng) where you have `-testclass` parameter:

> **-testclass** A comma-separated list of classes that can be found in your classpath.  A list of class files separated by commas (e.g. `org.foo.Test1,org.foo.test2`).

So you should be able to kick off your tests execution like:

1. For `com.az.testsFlux.TestsFluxPro` :

   ```
   java -cp "/path/to/test.jar;/path/to/test/dependencies/*" org.testng.TestNG -testclass com.az.testsFlux.TestsFluxPro
   ```
2. For `com.az.testsFlux.TestsVente`

   ```
   java -cp "/path/to/test.jar;/path/to/test/dependencies/*" org.testng.TestNG -testclass com.az.testsFlux.TestsVente
   ```
3. To run both:

   ```
   java -cp "/path/to/test.jar;/path/to/test/dependencies/*" org.testng.TestNG -testclass com.az.testsFlux.TestsVente,com.az.testsFlux.TestsFluxPro
   ```
4. etc.

Comment: If it is a maven project, it's possible to specify the configurable `testng.xml` from within `pom.xml` using surefire plugin.

Comment: See **Running 'testnames' in test tag** chapter of the [Maven Sufefire Plugin - Using TestNG](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html)

Comment: Thanks you i will try this solution